# Текст превратить в ссылку

Tags: php

Здравствуй ХешКод! Подскажитте как можно превратить ссылку в виде текста: http://google.com на

```
<a href = "http://google.com">http://google.com</a>
```

Я пробовал использовать str_replace(text); но дело в том что помимо ссылки, там может быть и просто текст.

Comment: preg_replace  ? составьте уже сами нужное выражение...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$переменная_с_текстом = preg_replace("#(https?|ftp)://\S+[^\s.,> )\];'\"!?]#",'<a href="\\0">\\0</a>',$переменная_с_текстом);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но можете рассказать что это за набор символов

    #(https?|ftp)://\S+[^\s.,> )\];'\"!?]#

Comment: Это регулярное выражение http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Ссылки вида www.google.ru, google.ru распознавать не будет. И смысл тогда этого регулярного выражения?

Comment: @Modal а кто в ТЗ писал что надо распознавать ещё и домены ? там вообще только про http:// написано

Comment: @Johniek а кто сказал что в url запятых нельзя ?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется так будет лучше:

`$site = "http://google.com";
$pattern = "/^((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9]{1})((\.[a-z0-9-])|([a-z0-9-]))*\.([a-z]{2,6})(\/?)$/";
$replace = "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>";
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $site);
echo $result;`

Answer (score 0):

При вводе строки "Hi this my site: site.net",
выводит "Hi this my site: [site.net](http://site.net)";

---

```
function s_link ($text){
    $arrt = array();
    $arrt = explode(" ", $text);
    $dot;
    for($i=0;$i<count($arrt);$i++){
        if(strpos($arrt[$i],".")){
            $dot .= "<a href='http://".$arrt[$i]."'>".$arrt[$i]."</a> ";
        }else{
            $dot .= $arrt[$i]." ";
        }
    }
    return $dot;
}
```

Comment: А насчет "просто текста" как быть?